# Bot Won't Clean the specific channel of Messages discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello I want the bot to clear a discord channel every 24 hours I changed the hours to seconds and it still hadn't cleared the channel I don't see anything wrong with the code, and I do not get any errors.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
import datetime
import calendar
import time
from datetime import date



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@tasks.loop(hours = 24)
async def daily_clean(ctx, bot):
  print("Successfully Purged")
  channel = client.get_channel(827603699735330837)
  await channel.purge(limit=100)

client.run("token")
```

Comment: You're not actually starting the task...

Answer (score 0):

Start the task under the on_ready() event.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am ready")
    daily_clean.start()
```

Also, remove `ctx` and `bot` from the func because I don't think tasks require/allow parameters.

Comment: They do allow arguments, but he’s not using them so there’s no point for them. Also putting things like that in the `on_ready` event is a bad idea, *from the docs:* `this function is not guaranteed to only be called once. `